# Cannot connect to Apple Push Notification server with telnet

Tags: networking, apple-push-notifications, port, telnet

Im trying to test connection to Apple Push Notification servers with:

```
telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
```

But I get the response:

```
Trying 17.172.232.48...
Trying 17.172.234.193...
Trying 17.172.234.185...
Trying 17.172.238.223...
Trying 17.172.232.50...
Trying 17.172.233.143...
Trying 17.172.232.41...
Trying 17.172.232.24...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the firewall.

Comment: Same problem here, what was the issue?